# Find the particular solution for this linear ODE $y' '-2y'+5y=e^x \cos2x$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the particular solution for this linear ODE :$y' '-2y'+5y=e^x \cos2x$.

How can I use Undetermined coefficients method ?

Answer (score 1):

$$y' '-2y'+5y=e^x \cos2x$$
Solve the homogeneous equation first:
$$y' '-2y'+5y=0$$
The characteristic polynomial is:
$$r^2-2r+5 =0 \implies r=1\pm 2i$$
The solution to the homogeneous equation  is therefore:
$$y_h(x)=e^{x}(c_1 \cos (2x)+c_2 \sin (2x))$$
Hence your guess for the particular solution should be
$$y_p(x)=xe^{x}(A\cos (2x)+B \sin (2x))$$
Plug the guess in the original equation and find the constants $A,B$. Then:
$$y(x)=y_h(x)+y_p(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

First, find the solution of the equation

$$y^2 - 2y + 5 = 0.$$

Then find a particular solution.